# Convert seconds value to the ISO 8601 format for duration in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, iso

I'm looking to convert a Oracle database column which holds seconds (music duration) to the ISO 8601 format for duration. But I've searched everywhere for an Oracle procedure or piece of SQL that does this without success. I see there are examples in other languages but not Oracle SQL or PL/SQL.

Here is some info on [the ISO standard](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm).

I'm on an Oracle 11g database.

Comment: Can you give a sample duration value and the result you expect? And the range you expect - can the duration ever exceed an hour, for example?

Comment: Yes, many compositions from Beethoven or Mazart are lasting more than 1 hour.

Comment: For anyone arriving here through search, with more recent Oracle versions we can use JSON to get ISO durations:
SELECT json_value(json_array(numtodsinterval(123456.789, 'second')), '$[0]') from dual; returns "P1DT10H17M36.789000S"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has an interval data type which you can convert your duration into, but you can't really format that. The simplest thing is break it down using mod and trunc to split the value into complete hours and minutes, and leftover seconds.

With some sample data:

```
with t (duration) as (
  select 59 from dual
  union all select 60 from dual
  union all select 61 from dual
  union all select 3599 from dual
  union all select 3600 from dual
  union all select 86399 from dual
)
select duration,
  numtodsinterval(duration, 'SECOND') as interval_value,
  'PT'
    || case when trunc(duration/3600) > 0 then trunc(duration/3600) || 'H' end
    || case when trunc(duration/3600) > 0 or trunc(mod(duration, 3600)/60) > 0
        then trunc(mod(duration, 3600)/60) || 'M' end
    || trunc(mod(duration, 60)) || 'S' as iso_value
from t;

  DURATION INTERVAL_VAL ISO_VALUE  
---------- ------------ ------------
        59 0 0:0:59.0   PT59S       
        60 0 0:1:0.0    PT1M0S      
        61 0 0:1:1.0    PT1M1S      
      3599 0 0:59:59.0  PT59M59S    
      3600 0 1:0:0.0    PT1H0M0S    
     86399 0 23:59:59.0 PT23H59M59S
```

I'm assuming the duration can never exceed 24 hours, and that you only want whole seconds; though longer durations and greater precision can be handled if necessary.

I'm also guessing that you want to exclude the highest optional part, so you wouldn't show 0H say; but that having shown hours you want to show minutes and seconds even if they are zero. You can tweak (or remove) the case statements if not.

To always show all three parts:

```
select duration,
  numtodsinterval(duration, 'SECOND') as interval_value,
  'PT' || trunc(duration/3600) || 'H'
    || trunc(mod(duration, 3600)/60) || 'M'
    || trunc(mod(duration, 60)) || 'S' as iso_value
from t;

  DURATION INTERVAL_VAL ISO_VALUE  
---------- ------------ ------------
        59 0 0:0:59.0   PT0H0M59S   
        60 0 0:1:0.0    PT0H1M0S    
        61 0 0:1:1.0    PT0H1M1S    
      3599 0 0:59:59.0  PT0H59M59S  
      3600 0 1:0:0.0    PT1H0M0S    
     86399 0 23:59:59.0 PT23H59M59S
```

To never show zero parts:

```
select duration,
  numtodsinterval(duration, 'SECOND') as interval_value,
  'PT'
    || case when trunc(duration/3600) > 0 then trunc(duration/3600) || 'H' end
    || case when trunc(mod(duration, 3600)/60) > 0 then trunc(mod(duration, 3600)/60) || 'M' end
    || case when trunc(mod(duration, 60)) > 0 then trunc(mod(duration, 60)) || 'S' end
    as iso_value
from t;

  DURATION INTERVAL_VAL ISO_VALUE  
---------- ------------ ------------
        59 0 0:0:59.0   PT59S       
        60 0 0:1:0.0    PT1M        
        61 0 0:1:1.0    PT1M1S      
      3599 0 0:59:59.0  PT59M59S    
      3600 0 1:0:0.0    PT1H        
     86399 0 23:59:59.0 PT23H59M59S
```

Comment: One again Mr Alex Poole does it again, that's fantastic I went with the never show zero part and works like a dream. Thank you :-) you've made my day.

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - Wernfried's extract approach gets the same output as my last query, with no zero elements, and is a bit cleaner - at least once you've converted your numeric value to an interval. I've just realised that neither deals with a duration of zero in the way the article you linked to says it should; my second query would, but for any of the others you'd need to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT INTERVAL '59' SECOND AS duration FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL '60' SECOND FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL '61' SECOND FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL '3599' SECOND FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL '3600' SECOND FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT INTERVAL '86399' SECOND FROM dual
)
SELECT duration,
    'PT'
        ||NULLIF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM duration)||'H', '0H') 
        ||NULLIF(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM duration)||'M', '0M') 
        ||NULLIF(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM duration)||'S', '0S')  
    AS iso_value
FROM t;
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning they'd need to do `numtodsinterval(duration, 'SECOND')` to convert from the original number of seconds to an interval.

Comment: `INTERVAL '59' SECOND AS duration` returns an `INTERVAL` data type.

Comment: Sure, but the OP is starting with numbers in the duration column, not an interval.